# mysql database logic

Tags: mysql, erd

My question is more of trying to understand what and how I can get something done. Here's the thing:

I got a job to build this application for a school to manage student bio data, work-out and handle student information and basic finance management.

Based on requirements I got from meets with my client, I have an ERD of a proposed MySQL Database with 23 different tables. The one part I would like to understand quickly is displaying data based on school terms. There are 3 terms in a year, each with its own summaries at the end of each term. At the end of 3 terms, a year has gone by and a student is promoted or demoted.

So my question is, how can I render my data to show 3 different terms and also to create a new year working out how to either promote a student or make the student repeat the class its in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

23 different tables?  I'd like to see that model.

I don't think you should have one table per term.  You'll have to keep adding tables every term, every year.

Sounds like a `transcript` table should have `term` and `year` columns that are incremented or decremented as a student progresses through.  It should also have a foreign key relationship with its `student`: it's a 1:1 between a student and their transcript.

I would have a separate `transcript` table because I'd prefer keeping it separate from basic personal information about a `student`.  A `transcript` would refer to the `courses` taken each term, the grade received for each, and calculate overall progress.  If I queried for the transcript for an individual student, I should be able to see every year, every term, every course, every grade in reverse chronological order.

Comment: +1 Agree with all, and I would add when designing your DB remember that it's easier and better to add columns than tables, and it's easier and better to add rows than columns.

Comment: duffymo I get what you are saying. I actually have something similar to what you are saying. I have basic student bio data separate, subjects in a separate table and the result or as you called it transcript table separate. But an additional question is following your explanation should i make the transcript table a view?

Comment: Bohemian, when you add columns rather than tables or rows rather than columns, does database obey 1,2 or 3NF? I tried to be as true as I could to these concepts.

Comment: @Eagletrophy 3NF. In fact, to be 3NF means you typically *need* to  do these things

Comment: No, no need for a view that I can see.